# Let Android app handle link URLs with configurable domain

Tags: android, android-intent, self-hosting

It is possible to open an Android app from within the browser by just clicking on a http/https URL when the app [registers itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2958701/282601) as [handler for the domain](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters) in its manifest.
The Jistsi Meet video-conferencing application [registers URL handlers](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) for the main domain `meet.jit.si`.

But I am running my own jitsi meet server, and I would like to share links to a video conference that work both in the desktop web browser (showing the web version of the conference), and open the Jitsi meet app on Android.

Is there some way to dynamically modify the intent registration in the Android app when the default domain setting is changed within the Jitsi app?

Example:

1. Standard intent domain is `meet.jit.si`
2. User changes default domain in the app settings to `meet.example.org`. New intent handler domain is `meet.example.org`, app opens when user clicks link to `https://meet.example.org/dummyconf`
3. Same for every other domain that gets configured.

Comment: Within what browser?  There's more than 1.  If you mean Chrome (probably the most common) you can, but you need a very special link.  See:  https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents  Please note that the intent from that might not work on all browsers.  I'm not sure why Chrome decided to make its own schema.

Comment: Any browser. A desktop user should be able to use that link and get the web version, and an Android user should get the app opened.

Comment: Then probably not possible with a single link.  I don't think all Android browsers support the chrome syntax, and the chrome syntax is not supported by other browsers.  You may be able to do it by changing the link based on referer OS and browser name.  Most browsers these days are Chrome on ANdroid, so I'd try using that format first-  it may work on desktop as well, unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Intent filters are too locked down:

- Registering a subdomain only (`meet.*`) does not work: `android:host` supports wildcards, but only at the beginning (for subdomains)

  > The asterisk must be the first character of the host attribute.
- Registering only a path (any domain, `/jitsi/MeetingName` as path) does not work because

  > If a host is not specified for the filter, the port attribute and all the path attributes are ignored.